# read-error on swap-device Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: swap

I'm using a Kingston USB 14GB as a swap area on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, and today the system crush and throw a message " read-error on swap-device "
, and the screen turn black, I tried to switch between shells but nothing work, so I forced the shutdown using the power button, what is the solution for this ?
I did run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

results from `smartctl --all /dev/sda`

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-33-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue Mobile
Device Model:     WDC WD5000LPCX-24C6HT0
Serial Number:    WD-WX51A35HSA1U
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6059cbe36
Firmware Version: 02.01A02
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep  3 21:36:43 2018 WEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 9120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 104) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   151   143   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1416
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       22183
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       6899
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2552
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       137
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   182   182   000    Old_age   Always       -       55366
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   104   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       6508

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Vendor (0x50)       Completed without error       00%      1247         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1247         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb

```
/dev/sdb: Unknown USB bridge [0x0930:0x6544 (0x100)]
```

sudo  smartctl --all /dev/sdc

```
Smartctl open device: /dev/sdc failed: No such device
```

Comment: Very likely the solution will be to replace the USB. Anyway, it is not ideal to use an USB for system or swap use.

Comment: @Fabby those are the results, however I solved the problem by making a swap file in the root

Comment: @Fabby the USB is not ruined, I should told you that I did formatted the USB as linux-swap and I did run the commands after I change my swap area to a new file in the root, so tell me if that effect the result please and if I should run a new command, but as I said I'm using a new file now in my root and that because I used all the 4 main partitions, I have a triple boot system

Comment: @Fabby what I really want to know is how to escape the black screen with the message when it appear, because the only way I could do it is by press the power button and shutdown the computer, thanks for your time

Comment: That would be [a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) (Nous ne demandons pas plus de Dirhams pout une question suppllémentaire)  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a swap file in my root and stopped using the USB.  I did:

Creating the swap file:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

Make the file only accessible to root:

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Use the file as swap space:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

If all that works and you want to make the above changes permanent:

```
sudo echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1071791/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)** (also upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

Turn the swapfile off like this :

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Create a new swap file on another disk: (where `X` and `Y` are the letters designating another device)

```
sudo mkswap -c /dev/XdY
```

Turn the swap file back on:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: Indeed !! Edited. Thx for noticing ;)

Comment: Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1071766/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)** (also upvoted as it's now a good answer!  **;-)**